# cakephp 3.0 create new widget by a plugin

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I created a new widget for cakephp 3.0 and now I would like to distribute it as a plugin.

My widget is at /src/View/Widget/Autocomplete.php

I baked the plugin and moved this file to /plugins/Autocomplete/src/View/Widget/Autocomplete.php

I want to let my plugin to load all neccessary helpers, css and js files. Where and how should I add them?

Comment: Can I suggest that you clarify this question? I think what you are asking is how to activate your Widget, so that it overrides the default Autocomplete.php widget. I also have this question. The documentation here does not explain this: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-custom-widgets

Answer (score 0):

You would add that information to the composer.json in your plugin. Here's an example:

https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/ccb5c35b4d525103e04a5b457ab5cf12f2e9a6b3/composer.json

Make sure you have the same data in "require", and change your "autoload" section accordingly

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer please? The link you sent is broken, and you don't outline any steps for loading the helpers, css, js files etc., so I wouldn't class this as an answer to the question. If you've done this before, do you mind sharing your knowledge?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you asked a new answer here in SO, so we can answer it

Comment: If I asked another question, it'd be very similar to what @RRD has asked. I see you've updated the link, but again, you don't actually explain anything. You link to an external resource with no context. OP explicitly asks for how to load helpers, CSS and JS files (which I'm interested in as well), but you don't mention these anywhere, and neither does the link you post to. Quite frankly, your "answer" only clouds the issue and is quite unhelpful. If you could actually _explain_ what you did, with examples, and break it down, then that would actually aid people going forward.

Comment: The problem is that this question is not even clear. I answered under the assumption he wanted his stuff published in packagist. If you have a more specific question I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: @JoséLorenzoRodríguez I think this is what he meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679980/how-to-make-plugins-widget-override-the-default-cakephp-basicwidget